# Receive event object in Vuex v-model setter

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a select element which receives & updates my Vuex store:

```
<select v-model:value="leadTrackNumber"  >
  <option v-for="(track, index) in tracks ">{{ index }}</option>
</select>
```

And here's the associated method:

```
leadTrackNumber: {
  get(){
    // process some data
    return leadTrackNumber
  },
  set(value){
    this.$store.commit('updateLeadTrack', value )
  },
},
```

I'd like to do something like `v-model:value="leadTrackNumber(value, $event)"` and then receive that in the method: `set(value, event)` (but of course that code doesn't work). Is this possible?

My intention is to use the received `event` argument to blur the select element. (With `event.target.blur()`)

I'd like to know the answer to this question for it's own sake, and am open to other ways to do that. (I can call a blur function on change as such: `@change="blurFunction($event)"`, but that only works if the value does actually change - I want it to blur no matter what.)

Comment: Why don't you use `@blur="onBlur($event)"`?

Comment: Blur is generally activated by a mouse click; in this case I want to utilize only keyboard input.

Comment: Since you're committing to the store, what about subscribing to the same commit in the component itself, and blurring out the `<select>` element? That is of course assuming there is a single element bound to the same computed property.

Comment: @Terry interesting idea... I'm not quite sure how you'd go about this, code-wise. What would that look like to "subscribe to the same commit in the component itself"? (Would you use a `$ref`? It seems like there would be a need to target the element directly. But if so I'm not quite sure why the store needs to be involved actually - couldn't that be done in the same component?)

Comment: I mean, you can "piggyback" on the store's commit to manually blur the element. Alternatively you can simply define a new method, e.g. `blurSelect` in your component, and call it in the setter of the computed property.

Comment: Aha, are you thinking of something like `this.$el.querySelector('select')`?

Answer (score 1):

As i understand: By default when you select an option the select tags gets outline color,which means it is focused.

But you don't want that.Instead you want when an option gets selected,to remove the focus from select.

There are couple ways.One is to toggle a css class and add/remove the ouline color.But i am going to show you how to do it with js and vue.

```
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected_item" @click="option_selected"> <!-- an option got selected so call the option_selected method -->
    <option :value="null">Select item</option>
    <option v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo.id" :value="todo.text">
      {{todo.text}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

And the Vue.js code:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    selected_item: null,
    todos: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript", id: 1 },
      { text: "Learn Vue", id: 2 },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", id: 3 },
      { text: "Build something awesome", id: 4 }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    option_selected(event) {
        event.target.blur()
    }
  }
})
```

Also check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Roland1993/wjm0874m/)

Comment: Thanks for this response. See my last paragraph above - `@change` only fires when the selection is in fact changed. Also to be clear regarding CSS, it's  not so much that I want to remove the highlighting, rather I want to remove the focus, because when a select element is focused, arrow keys change the value, and I am using the arrow keys for other things.

Comment: Then just change the change event to click event.So change the @change="changed" to @click="changed".It will work i tried it.Let me know if it worked for you

Comment: I also edit my answer and added a fiddle.Check it out

Comment: This does work once any option is clicked; alas the select option list now does not open on click as normal, because it immediately blurs on mouse-up. It is still possible to move to an option while the mouse is still down - but then the mouse must be released and the option clicked. So that doesn't feel right.